# Is it possible to use "should have" in a conditional sentence type 3?

Tags: sentence, conditionals

I know it's possible to say:
*If I had studied more, I **wouldn't have failed** my exam.*

Rules given in some Russian student's books let me say:
*If I had studied more, I **shouldn't have failed** my exam.*

But my American teacher says the above variant is impossible.

Whom should I believe? **Can we use "should have + verb (3 form)" in this case?**

Comment: This use of *should* still exists in BrE, but it's definitely on the way out (it's practically extinct in AmE).

Comment: It is possible but old-fashioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll speak to AmE.  Both *would* and *should* express an idea about an event that did not happen.  In this case, passing your exam.  That didn't happen:  instead you failed.  *Would* indicates the contingency of that failure on the conditional, i.e., passing the test required the extra study that you didn't do.

*Should* indicates a failed expectation based on an event that occurred, not a hypothetical one introduced by *if*.  So you would say

> I studied so hard that I **shouldn't** have failed my exam.

Here you actually did the study, but contrary to expectations, you still failed the exam.

This distinction has changed over time.  Consider this passage from *The boys' and girls' book of story and tale* published in 1881:

> The king scratched his head, and in doing so nearly knocked his crown
>   off. "All my family are very clever," he said.
>  I'm sure I
>   **shouldn't have** thought so," returned the queen, rather sharply, "and I don't know what particular good cleverness is to do a woman[.]"

The queen means that if she had known all of husband's family, she **would** have reached the opposite conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your teacher -- I don't think "shouldn't" is possible there (at least in American English) because "should" expresses obligation while "would" expresses contingency, and the latter is at issue in this context.